# processing - pythagorean theorem to calculate distance between mouse pointer and x,y

Tags: processing

I am trying to make all the spheres that are closer to the pointer darker using the pythagorean theorem. I'm not sure why my mouseMoved is not working. If someone could please look over my code and see where my mistake is?

```
int numBalls = 100;
float spring = 0.17;
float gravity = 0;
float friction = -1;
float value = 255;
Ball[] balls = new Ball[numBalls];

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    balls[i] = new Ball(random(width), random(height), random(5, 60), i, balls);
  }

  noStroke();
  fill(value);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  for (Ball ball : balls) {
     ball.collide();
     ball.move();
     ball.display();  
  }
}

class Ball {
  float x, y;
  float diameter;
  float vx = 0;
  float vy = 0;

  int id;
  Ball[] others;

  Ball(float xin, float yin, float din, int idin, Ball[] oin) {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    diameter = din;
    id = idin;
    others = oin;
  } 

  void collide() {
    for (int i = id + 1; i < numBalls; i++) {
      float dx = others[i].x - x;
      float dy = others[i].y - y;
      float distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  float minDist = others[i].diameter/2 + diameter/2;
  if (distance < minDist) { 
    float angle = atan2(dy, dx);
    float targetX = x + cos(angle) * minDist;
    float targetY = y + sin(angle) * minDist;
    float ax = (targetX - others[i].x) * spring;
    float ay = (targetY - others[i].y) * spring;
    vx -= ax;
    vy -= ay;
    others[i].vx += ax;
    others[i].vy += ay;
       }
    }   
  }

   void move() {
     vy += gravity;
     x += vx;
     y += vy;

if (x + diameter/15 > width) {
  x = width - diameter/15;
  vx *= friction; 
}

else if (x - diameter/15 < 0) {
  x = diameter/15;
  vx *= friction;
}

if (y + diameter/15 > height) {
  y = height - diameter/15;
  vy *= friction; 
} 

else if (y - diameter/15 < 0) {
  y = diameter/15;
  vy *= friction;
}
```

}

```
   void display() {
      ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
   }

  float d = sqrt((x - y) * (x - y)  + (mouseX - mouseY) * (mouseX - mouseY) );

  void mouseMoved () {  
    value = value - 85;

    if (d < 75) {
      fill (value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam this is in the processing program. not sure what language

Comment: I see, that is actually a language, I hadn't heard of it before. I'm removing the functional-programming tag as it isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

You made two major mistakes. First one is about theorem it should be calculated like this:

```
sqrt((ball.x - mouseX) * (ball.x - mouseX) + (ball.y - mouseY) * (ball.y - mouseY))
```

Second one: if you want use mouse events they can't be overridden inside your class just like that (you just created your own function called `mouseMoved` that has nothing to do with [mouse event](https://processing.org/examples/mousefunctions.html)). To simply override them place it outside any class at the end of the sketch. Also when you change `fill` value it will influence all balls not just the close one due to nature of processing language as state machine (find more about `fill()` [here](https://processing.org/tutorials/color/)).

Now you can just delete `mouseMoved()` and for better understanding  add this lines instead `ball.display();` inside `draw` function:

```
void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (Ball ball : balls) {
    ball.collide();
    ball.move();        
    float d = sqrt((ball.x - mouseX) * (ball.x - mouseX)  + (ball.y - mouseY) * (ball.y - mouseY) );
    if(d<75) ball.display();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps and if you have any comments or questions post it here.

Comment: doesn't really answer the question, but worthwhile pointing out... **sqrt calculation are very costly**, any time you can avoid it. you should. instead of comparing the `float d` to 75, you should consider using `dSquared` to `75*75`. where dSquared is `(ball.x - mouseX) * (ball.x - mouseX)  + (ball.y - mouseY) * (ball.y - mouseY)`